# What's the hair of the blackhole?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, string-theory

Quote:

> The no-hair theorem states that all stationary black hole solutions of the Einstein–Maxwell equations of gravitation and electromagnetism in general relativity can be completely characterized by only three independent externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem))

But the recent study stated the hair of the blackhole seemed to indicate the stability of the blackhole. What was the hair in this case then?(the geometry of the surface or the entanglement of the pair production?) either, wasn't this a contradiction of the no-hair theorem? Does that mean in string theory or the QFT in general, the description of the no hair theorem was revised?

What's the hair of the blackhole?

Comment: The no-hair theorem is a statement about the limitation of the theory at this moment. It is not automatically a statement about actual black holes. To make it a valid statement about black holes we would have to observe whether black holes do or do not have "surface structure". If they do, then general relativity breaks down near the event horizon, if they don't, then it still makes valid predictions in that regime.

Comment: @FlatterMann So in string theory or QFT near the neighborhood of the black hole, it's nature to discuss the possible structure or "hair" of the black hole or the interaction, and no hair theorem simply does not apply?